# Polybase - Error converting data type VARCHAR to DATETIME

Tags: sql-server, azure-synapse, polybase

I'm trying to create an external table to a CSV file stored in Azure Storage.

The CSV data looks like this :-

| Date | Rail Period | Calendar Year | Calendar Month | Calendar Month Name | Fiscal Year | Fiscal Period | Weekday | Weekday Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 26/04/2021 | 2201 | 2021 | 4 | April | 2022 | Period 1 | Monday | 1 |
| 27/04/2021 | 2201 | 2021 | 4 | April | 2022 | Period 1 | Tuesday | 2 |
| 28/04/2021 | 2201 | 2021 | 4 | April | 2022 | Period 1 | Wednesday | 3 |
| 29/04/2021 | 2201 | 2021 | 4 | April | 2022 | Period 1 | Thursday | 4 |
| 30/04/2021 | 2201 | 2021 | 4 | April | 2022 | Period 1 | Friday | 5 |
| 01/05/2021 | 2201 | 2021 | 5 | May | 2022 | Period 2 | Saturday | 6 |
| 02/05/2021 | 2202 | 2021 | 5 | May | 2022 | Period 2 | Sunday | 7 |
| 03/05/2021 | 2202 | 2021 | 5 | May | 2022 | Period 2 | Monday | 1 |
| 04/05/2021 | 2202 | 2021 | 5 | May | 2022 | Period 2 | Tuesday | 2 |

I've created the External File Format using the following code

```
CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT csvFile
WITH (
    FORMAT_TYPE = DELIMITEDTEXT,
    FORMAT_OPTIONS (
      FIELD_TERMINATOR = ',',
      STRING_DELIMITER = '"',
      FIRST_ROW = 2,
      USE_TYPE_DEFAULT = TRUE,
      ENCODING = 'UTF8' )
);
```

and the External table as follows

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ext.DateDimension(
    [Date]                DATE, 
    [Rail Period]         INT, 
    [Calendar Year]       INT, 
    [Calendar Month]      INT,
    [Calendar Month Name] VARCHAR(9),
    [Fiscal Year]         INT, 
    [Fiscal Period]       VARCHAR(9), 
    [Weekday]             VARCHAR(9), 
    [Weekday Number]      INT)
WITH(
    DATA_SOURCE = [tfwpbstore_ADLSG2], 
    LOCATION = '/Generic Datasets/Date Dimension.csv',
    FILE_FORMAT = csvFile);
```

However, when I try to SELECT from the external table it gives me the following error

> Msg 107090, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> HdfsBridge::recordReaderFillBuffer - Unexpected error encountered filling record reader buffer: HadoopSqlException: Error converting data type VARCHAR to DATETIME.

and I'm not quite sure what's wrong. If anyone could help, I'd be most grateful.

Comment: `'26/04/2021'` is a language specific date format; specifically it'll likely only work if your language setting is set to `BRITISH`. I suspect Synapse or Polybase dislikes that as it's probably working in American `ENGLISH`. if you can ensure your value is language agnostic, you'd be better off. I.e. `yyyyMMdd` or `yyyy-MM-dd` (the latter is only agnostic for the new date and type data types).

Comment: Prior to loading the CSV, you can SET DATEFORMAT DMY

Comment: … https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-file-format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=delimited#date_format

Comment: @Larnu @lptr Thank you very much all - I included `DATE_FORMAT = 'dd/MM/yyyy'` and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above I needed to define the date format used in the file format statement as follows:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT csvFile_ddMMyyyy_fr2
WITH (
    FORMAT_TYPE = DELIMITEDTEXT,
    FORMAT_OPTIONS (
      FIELD_TERMINATOR = ',',
      STRING_DELIMITER = '"',
     DATE_FORMAT = 'dd/MM/yyyy',
      FIRST_ROW = 2,
      USE_TYPE_DEFAULT = TRUE,
      ENCODING = 'UTF8' )
);
```